# How can I ask intellj to reindex

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ build is successful but still complaining compilation issues when running the app.

I always invalidate my cache and force reindexing, this wastes lot of time and focus.

I can I avoid this issue. ie (How can I ask intellj to reindex.)

Comment: Hello, it seems you're a new contributor! Whenever you ask something on stackoverflow, you should follow some [common practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a question, like posting the code you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Please report in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the steps to reproduce and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

There is no other way to force reindex except File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart or deleting the [system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory) manually while the IDE is not running.